# Where can I find popular video game code in C++?

Tags: c++

i'm learning c++ in my high school computer science class and I wanted to look at what actual c++ coding looks like, I feel like we spent the whole year on such a small portion of the programming language and my knowledge feels useless. I want to see if I can understand it to know where I stand with it, I am also just curious. My teacher told me that only a small percentage of games are made with c++ but, some he mentioned that might be made with (mostly) c++ were Halo, Diablo and some online role playing games. I read that its illegal to look at the code or you cant get it but if you have the game on your computer shouldn't the code be on there too? How do you extract/view it? Thanks

Comment: No, to run the game, you don't need code. All you need is a binary, and that binary could come from anywhere.

Comment: [Doom 3 source code](https://github.com/id-Software/DOOM-3-BFG)

Comment: If you want to look at C++, then games are hardly the place to start. First of all, modern games are *huge*, secondly they are highly optimized, which means the code is in places virtually unreadable.

Comment: In general, look for "Open Source" games. Open source are projects where the source code is publicly available. A web search should show you quite a few.

Comment: C++ compiles down to machine code. Imagine you took the English language, wrote a sentence, read it aloud, and looked at the sound waves. You could listen to the result, but you can not read the soundwave. This is not a perfect analogy, but I hope it helps you understand how compiling works. If you see a project that says "Open Source" that means they give you the uncompiled code for free. This is what you want to look at.

Comment: Your teacher is wrong about "only a small percentage of games" being made in C++.  Pretty much all modern AAA games are written in C++.  There are sometimes a few other languages involved, for example many games embed a scripting language of some kind (lua is common) to make adding complex content easier.  The only thing I can think he might have meant is that old (the original Nintendo, for example) games were often written in assembly.

Comment: Also, although there are a few games for which the source code is available, they're a bad place to start -- they're huge and game developers have something of a reputation for being sloppy programmers -- they write really amazing programs, but they're not really meant to be read by people outside of the team and are a bad way to learn in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Doom 3](https://github.com/id-Software/DOOM-3-BFG) is available for reading and is written in C++, it is well regarded as well. Note that it doesn't use C++11 or other modern methodologies.

On the topic of game making, the vast majority of AAA games are made in C++. Counting individual games other languages win out, but that is due to mobile platforms being so easy to publish to.

Answer (score 2):

Id software's quake was released on GPL:

[Quake on Github](https://github.com/id-Software/Quake)

You can also look for other open source games.

Answer (score 0):

> I read that its illegal to look at the code or you cant get it

That would be referring to decompiling/disassembling/reverse-engineering someone else's code which depending on where you are from and the reasons is illegal

> but if you have the game on your computer shouldn't the code be on there too?

On your computer would be the compiled binary which is not in a human readable form and would require being decompiled/disassembled/reverse-engineered

> My teacher told me that only a small percentage of games are made with c++ but, some he mentioned that might be made with (mostly) c++ were Halo, Diablo and some online role playing games.

That would depend on when the game was made and what the target platform was, C++ was used for a lot since it was known as being the most efficient along with C so it was seen as necessary for games. Now however there have been improvements in the processing speeds of computers as well as the efficiency of the languages themselves opening the realm to many languages. Java on Android, Objective-C/Swift on iOS, C# on XBox, etc.

On a PC at this point almost any language can be utilized to write a game, it all depends on what the development team is familiar with and any other factors each team needs to consider for themselves.

DOOM-3 along with many other pieces of id-Software were open sourced years after their release if you wish to browse the source of an actual game. https://github.com/id-Software/DOOM-3